# @Transactional and Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

What I understand so far is that when you use the @Transactional annotation any failure will cause the operation to rollback to its previous state.I have this method which adds Items to a quotation using spring PagingAndSortingRepository Interface.

```
@Override
        public Quotation createNewQuotation(PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest, Supplier supplier) {
        Quotation quotation = new Quotation();
        Date now = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        quotation.setQuotationDate(now);
        quotation.setPurchaseRequest(purchaseRequest);
        quotation.setSupplier(supplier);
        quotationRepository.save(quotation);
        return quotation;

    }
```

When I put a @Transactional annotation on the whole class and manually testing if the operation will rollback (by not selecting any supplier), other properties like quotationDate, PurchaseRequest is still stored in the database.

I get the feeling that I'm not using the @Transactional annotation. What might be the problem and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What might be the problem and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Ok, have you configured to use a transaction manager in your spring config? Can you show your spring config?

Comment: I'm using Springboot. Are there any configuration required to make this work? i've been using this https://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/ as a reference.

Comment: "@Transactional annotation any failure will cause the operation to rollback to its previous state" -- This is not true, only unchecked exceptions are rollbacked by default.

Comment: Also, {@Transactional} annotations are only evaluated when you have 
     @EnableTransactionManagement.

Comment: What does that mean in the context of my problem? is it normal that a new quotation will be saved in the database despite not supplying the method with a supplier parameter?

Comment: I tried adding `@EnableTransactionManagement` on top of my `@SpringBootApplication`. I got this error Description:

The bean 'purchaseRequestServiceImpl' could not be injected as a 'com.eprocurement.service.PurchaseRequestServiceImpl' because it is a
JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
        com.eprocurement.service.PurchaseRequestService


Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.

I made this work by adding a `@EnableTransactionManagement` on my main class.
I solved the

> The bean 'purchaseRequestServiceImpl' could not be injected as a
>   'com.eprocurement.service.PurchaseRequestServiceImpl' because it is a
>   JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
>   com.eprocurement.service.PurchaseRequestService Action: Consider
>   injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of
>   CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync
>   and/or @EnableCaching.

by placing the `@Transactional` annotation on my service interfaces and `@autowiring` it instead of `@autowiring` my implementation classes.